# Enums without type specification and auto-conflict resolution in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Is it possible to use enums without full type specification?

Reason is that I would like to have nice and clean DSL-like code. Similar to how the literal string type works in TypeScript.

Example (not working):

```
enum class HAlign { left, center, right }
enum class VAlign { top, center, down }

fun main() {
  val align: HAlign = center 
  // it should corectly resolve it as HAlign.center
  // and auto-resolve conflict between HAlign.center and VAlign.center 
}
```

Comment: You can `import HAlign.center` and then just write `center` in your main code, but you won't be able to also `import VAlign.center` without aliasing one of them.

Comment: @BenP. thanks, I intentionally chosed example with conflicting names, as it's very frequent case. Sadly, seems like as you said, Kotlin can't resolve it.